# Regular expression for matching string from result (Javascript/Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, regex, logging

new to regex and nodejs. I have a program that calls a function then displays (result) in console such as below. How would a regular expression look like to match the "on":false string:

```
 {
   "state": {
   "on": false,
   "name": name,
   "date": date,
   "value": 254,
  },
 }
```

I currently have this but not really working for me. Does anyone have any idea what regular expression I would use to capture "ONLY" : "on":false, ?? Any help, suggestions greatly appreciated.

```
call.getStatus(22, function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    displayStatus(result);
    var re = new RegExp("/^"on":false,$\");
    if (re.test(displayStatus)) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }   
});
```

Comment: Do you want to parse the string (JSON) into an object **=>** use `JSON.parse`!

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir  I'm trying to write a pass/fail case that looks at the "on":false and marks returns fail. To display the status I have: var displayStatus = function(status){
 console.log(JSON.stringify(status, null, 2));
};

Comment: `displayStatus` is a function so this `re.test(displayStatus)` is wrong! I think you meant `re.test(result)`!

Comment: ahh yes I see, thanks! Any idea or link to references on how to correctly syntax what I need to capture in regex

Comment: Why not just parse the string and turn it into an object `x` using `JSON.parse()` and then just check if `x['on'] === false`? Seems a lot easier than kludging regexc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're sure that the substring will be `"on": false` then you can use `indexOf` like this:

```
call.getStatus(22, function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    displayStatus(result);
    if (result.indexOf('"on": false') !== -1) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }   
});
```

Or to be safe, using a regex like this:

```
call.getStatus(22, function(err, result){
    if (err) throw err;
    displayStatus(result);
    var re = /"on"\s*:\s*false*/;
    if (re.test(result)) {
        console.log("Valid");
    } else {
        console.log("Invalid");
    }   
});
```

I used a regular expression literal (`/.../`) that looks for the srting `"on"` followed by 0 or more spaces `\s*` followed by a `:` and 0 or more spaces and finally `false`.